# IIS Rewrite rule seems happens twice

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, redirect, url-rewrite-module

I have a simple rewrite rule as follows:

```xml
<rule name="short url" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="redirect(.*)" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="pages(.*)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/redirect?page={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

However, if a put a breakpoint in our code on the redirect target page it gets hit twice.

Why would this happen?

Comment: What is the URL that is hit twice?

Comment: action type="Redirect" url="/redirect?page={R:1}"